# Regex.Replace why does \b prevent this?

Tags: .net, regex

Why does the second statement fail?

works

```
Regex.Replace("zz WHERE zz", "where", "yy", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

does not

```
Regex.Replace("zz WHERE zz", "\bwhere\b", "yy", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

This works to but replaces the space which i do not want to do

```
Regex.Replace("zz WHERE zz", " where ", "yy", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `\b` is the backspace control character (U+0008). The backslashes themselves there don't even get to the regular expression.

To use it as intended in a regular expression you need to either double-escape (escape the backslashes for C#'s string so they are normal backslashes for the regex):

```
"\\bwhere\\b"
```

or use a verbatim string literal:

```
@"\bwhere\b"
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the backslashes in C#, or else use a verbatim string literal `@`:

```
@"\bwhere\b"
```